# Edit UiTabBar without More-Tab?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbar

Is there a way to let the user edit a UITabBar without the "more"-Tab? I have a UiTabbar with just 4 TabItems, so there is no more tab. 
I tried setEditing: YES, but nothing happend.

Any idea, how its possible?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a UITabBar then you can call the method `beginCustomizingItems:`, passing in an array of UITabBarItems. iOS handles the rest, including presenting the view controller to edit.

This doesn't work if it's a UITabBarController, even though you can access the UITabBar property (in this case, you will have to implement your own way of customizing the bar).

Comment: i have a uitabbarcontroller so, there is no easy way?